Problem playing audio loop from Firebase with dart audioplayers
I'm trying to play a simple audio from a wav file on firebase. I a function that seems pretty straightforward but it doesn't work. I've included the error right after the function. Has anyone experienced something similar? Can anyone help me fix it?
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

Future<void> playLoopAction(String? loopPath) async {
  if (loopPath == null) {
    print('Error: loopPath is null');
    return;
  }

  // Retrieve the audio player instance from app state
  AudioPlayer? audioPlayer = FFAppState().playingLoop;

  if (audioPlayer != null) {
    try {
      // Stop any currently playing audio
      await audioPlayer.stop();

      // Load the audio file from the URL
      // Set the loop mode to infinite
      audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);

      // Play the loaded audio
      await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(loopPath));
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error setting audio source: $e');
    }
  } else {
    print('Error: audioPlayer is null');
  }
}

I get this error when testing on web:
Error debug serializing parameter: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'AudioPlayer'
dart_sdk.js:37972 AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException( UrlSource(url: http...), PlatformException(WebAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, MediaError: MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Format error (Code: 4), null)
dart_sdk.js:37972 Error setting audio source: PlatformException(WebAudioError, Failed to set source. For troubleshooting, see https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md, MediaError: MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Format error (Code: 4), null)
It's weird because all of the other info from the query comes through with no problem, I can display the name and other meta information but I just can't play the audio. If anyone could help me I will be eternally grateful
I was expecting the audio to play
